# Can't get tabs to work in HTML & JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not a JavaScript person so I'm having a little difficulty with what I'm trying to do.  We have a html page that is supposed to display "tabs" for 3 different details of our product: Description, Details, and Returns.  I can get the tabs to display correctly but the JavaScript isn't changing to the tab when I click on the tab header.

[image]

Here's my html, pretty basic:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="skeleton.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <br><br><br>
    <ul class="sans tabs"> 
        <li>
            <a class="active" href="#tabinfo" style="fonrt-weight:normal">Description</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#tabdetails" style="fonrt-weight:normal;color:#999">Details</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#returns" style="fonrt-weight:normal;color:#999">Delivery & Returns</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="tabs-content"> 
        <li class="active" id="tabinfo">
            <p>A description of the product would go here.  A description of the product would go here.  A description of the product would go here.  
            A description of the product would go here.  A description of the product would go here.  A description of the product would go here.  A description of the product would go here.</p>
        </li>
        <li id="tabdetails">
            <ul>
                <li>Detail #1</li>
                <li>Detail #2</li>
                <li>Detail #3</li>
                <li>Detail #4</li>
                <li>Detail #5</li>
                <li>etc.</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="returns">
            <p>Details about returning a product would go here.</p>
            <p>Details about returning a product would go here.</p>
            <p>See <a href="/somelink/">Delivery & Returns</a> for more information.</p>
        </li> 
    </ul>
    <script src="tabs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and of course, the tabs.js file:

```
$('body').on('click', 'ul.tabs > li > a', function(e) {

    //Get Location of tab's content
    var contentLocation = $(this).attr('href');

    //Let go if not a hashed one
    if(contentLocation.charAt(0)=="#") {

        e.preventDefault();

        //Make Tab Active
        $(this).parent().siblings().children('a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        //Show Tab Content & add active class
        $(contentLocation).show().addClass('active').siblings().hide().removeClass('active');

    }
});
```

Again, I don't know a whole lot about js so I'm sure it's something to do with that but right now I'm stuck and can't figure it out.

Comment: You're including tabs.js whioch seems to rely on some jQuery code but you're not including the jquery.js file which you'll need to have.

Comment: What is ´tabs.js´? Do you have a link?

Comment: non related but `fonrt-weight` doesnt exist, it should be `font-weight` on your tab links - a typo i assume :)

Comment: I started a jsfiddle for you but can't go any further without more information. http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/VvwSH/

Comment: @Xotic750 - 'tabs.js' is in my original question...the code at the bottom.

Comment: Well, there doesn't appear to be enough code to make any tabs appear, see for yourself. You could just point me towards the included file ..

Comment: I got the fiddle running....really, really strange here....It worked as expected without any css being applied...so I thought it might be in one of my css files and when I added those, it still rendered just fine....odd...not too sure what to make of it. http://jsfiddle.net/VvwSH/2/

Comment: Yes, that is working fine for me too.

Comment: Is there a way in jsFiddle to export the results as an html file?

Comment: Right click, save as web page. Why don't you try linking to your actual external files to see if it works? In the external resources menu.

Comment: Add /show to the fiddle and view-source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your statement in a ready statement.. i.e

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $('body').on('click', 'ul.tabs > li > a', function(e) {

        //Get Location of tab's content
        var contentLocation = $(this).attr('href');

        //Let go if not a hashed one
        if(contentLocation.charAt(0)=="#") {

            e.preventDefault();

            //Make Tab Active
            $(this).parent().siblings().children('a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');

            //Show Tab Content & add active class
            $(contentLocation).show().addClass('active').siblings().hide().removeClass('active');

        }
    });

});
```

This could be neatened up as well:

```
$('body').on('click', 'ul.tabs > li > a', function(e) {
```

could become

```
$('.tabs').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
```

Comment: I wasn't sure if that was just a typo in the question or in the file itself, but yes that will definitely cause an issue

Comment: I couldn't decide either, but the rest of it looked ok so i thought it must of been

Comment: I couldn't get SO to render that first line correctly without the tick marks, it was showing it as plain text, so I used those just to get code to display....in the js, they are not included.

Comment: This was the issue....without the `.ready` line of code, the `a` tag was getting dropped off.  Big thanks to @DannyHearnah and @Xotic750 for helping me get this resolved!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this [jquery ui tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/). you will find all the code you need and an explanation on how to apply it in the link provided

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Click handler on the Tab headers, instead of on the body

```
$("body ul.tabs li").click(function() {
  // the function goes here.
});
```

This is assuming that you're using jQuery. If you're not already using it, you should add this under the head section.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" />
```

Comment: I made the changes as you suggested but now my page won't render at all.  I believe it has something to do with the jquery.min.js link because if I remove that (just for testing purposes), the page will render.  ???

Comment: If you're not looking at the page over http/s you'll need to add that into the `src` attribute.. so change `src="//` to `src="http://`

Comment: also not all browsers allow self-closing script tag; <script></script> is less error-prone

Comment: Thanks for those tips...this got the page to render correctly, however, when clicking on any tab, it still doesn't change.  Am I missing something?